# Add additional feature to Windows Explorer

Tags: c#, windows-7, windows-services

I am a C#.Net developer.

How can I add an extra option to the Windows 7 Explorer. For example, in the folder listing view(which lists Name, Size, Date Modified and so on), I need to add my own feature to display number of child folders. 
Where from I can start ? Will a 'Windows Service' suffice for this ?
The question is related to the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161499/windows-explorer-how-to-create-additional-button).

After reading some answers,

This link provides much details about Properties

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff728870%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

But where should I start ? Should I create a Class Library solution in Visual Studio 2010 ? Is there any tutorial related with this in the web ?

Comment: There are no tutorials because this is rarely done. There is documentation, which you should spend a few days reading. Then maybe you can come back and give us a tutorial. Hint: It's a COM object so you need a COM-visible DLL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a Shell Extension, not a windows service. In particular you need to create a "custom property".

Start with the documentation here:

- Creating Custom Properties: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144135(v=vs.85).aspx